# Automatize user accounts

Tags: users, database

I have a database with x users. I would like to add those accounts on my drupal database without having to recreate them one by one.

I would like to do a script mike that but i'm not really sure it would work out :

```
username = select name from mybase;
pw = select password from mybase;
mail = select mail from mybase;

drush ucrt username --mail=mail --password=pw
```

Obviously it would be a loop for every user, but i just wanted to share the idea.
First of all, is it possible to do this in shell ? The database is in another server, i'm not sure i can connect and take bake information (maybe using ssh ?)
Also the password is hashed in the other database, won't it generate a bad password (by hashing a hashed password). Even so, this point is not a problem, i can reinitialize their password to their login.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the Migrate module.  As it has a 'destination' class that deals with User imports for you.

The easiest way is to import into your database and use the 'MigrateSourceSQL' class as your 'source.

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate

Answer (score 0):

With https://www.drupal.org/project/user_import you can import users from a CSV file.

Export the users in phpMyAdmin, MySQL workbench, or whatever you are using to manage the database (take a look at 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE' if it's a lot of users).